# Get number of files in directory with pathlib python

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a two directories with csv files. Both should be of the same length, as I am looping over both of them with zip. Therefor I have a check to see if the length of them are the same. The code looks like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
def check():
    base = Path('home/user/src/log').rglob('*.csv')
    test = Path('home/user/src/log').rglob('*.csv')
    print(list(base))
    if len(list(base)) != len(list(test):
        print(f"Wrong number of files in {str(base)} and {str(test)}")
        return -1 
    for base, test in zip(base, test):
        x = pd.read_csv(base)
        y = pd.read_csv(test)
        print(x)
        print(y)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    check()
```

The `list(base)` gives the list of files, but it also silent kills the program. So if I have `print(list(base))` it will print the files in base and then the program terminates.
The `str(base)` does also not work, but this is because I havent found a way to print out the directory path without the program terminating afterwards. Any tips to get the length of the list and print the directory without killing the program.

Note: I now I can use 'os' but would like to use pathlib if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rglob` returns a generator. Calling `list` on the generator consumes all items.

You could however convert it to a list initially and then keep working with the list afterwards:

```
from pathlib import Path
def check():
    base = list(Path('home/user/src/log').rglob('*.csv'))
    test = list(Path('home/user/src/log').rglob('*.csv'))
    print(base)
    if len(base) != len(test):
        print(f"Wrong number of files in {str(base)} and {str(test)}")
        return -1 
    for base, test in zip(base, test):
        x = pd.read_csv(base)
        y = pd.read_csv(test)
        print(x)
        print(y)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    check()
```